# including a php file in an email

Tags: php, email, include

Hey ya'll I have this piece of code here and what I am trying to do is include what is in this html file into an email, but it doesnt appear to be working :( are the mime types okay? is php include not what I am looking for?

```
        $to = "email@domainname.com";
        $subject = "Late Notice";
        $message .= include("latenotice.html");
        $from = "myfriend@hisdomainname.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Include opens and evaluates a file. You probably want something like fopen() instead.

Comment: @j08691: file_get_contents is much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include` doesn't return a string.  It executes the file, which means the HTML will be echoed to the screen.

Try `file_get_contents` instead.

```
$message .= file_get_contents("latenotice.html");
```

Note: This will **not** execute any PHP code in the file.  If you want that, you can use output buffering.

```
ob_start();
include("latenotice.html");
$message .= ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks Rocket, works like a charm ;) I will be able to accept in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

If you want the to "return" something after an include, you need to put a return at the end of  the file you include.

Like file.php

```
 return "My String";
```

Email.php

```
$var = include('file.php'); // "My String"
```

In your case use [file_get_contents](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: a return does nothing unless there's something to return. `return;` by itself wouldn't include the file's source.

Answer (score 1):

`include` only evaluates to a value when the included file `return`s something - `latenotice.html` probably just contains the content. I think you want to read the file:

```
$message .= file_get_contents("latenotice.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Include](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) doesn't return a string, it includes executable code in the script.

You are probably looking for [`file_get_contents`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$message .= file_get_contents('latenotice.html');
```

Also, you should look at a PEAR lib like [Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected); attachments and mime types are not trivial to get right.